# How can I get rid of the brackets and comma in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to swap two integers. this is my code so far. when I input for example:

```
3
8
```

the output is

```
(8,3)
```

when i want it to be:

```
8 3
```

How do I get rid of the brackets and the comma in between?

this is my code so far:

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    user_val1, user_val2 = user_val2, user_val1
    user = user_val1, user_val2
    return user

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)
    print (swap_values(user_val1, user_val2))
```

Comment: change this `swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)` to this `user_val1 , user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)`

Comment: this shows up 3 times in my code, which do i change"?

Comment: don't print function call print the values

Comment: There are many places on line that teach you to format and otherwise arrange your output.  Stack Overflow is not intended to substitute for existing tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    user_val1, user_val2 = user_val2, user_val1    
    return user_val1, user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    user_val1, user_val2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)
    print (user_val1, user_val2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are returning the values from `swap_values` function as a `tuple`, you will need to assign those values to two variables, and then print those variables.

Please take a look:

```py
def swap_values(user_val1, user_val2):
    user_val1, user_val2 = user_val2, user_val1
    return user_val1, user_val2

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    user_val1 = int(input())
    user_val2 = int(input())
    user1, user2 = swap_values(user_val1, user_val2)
    print(f"{user1} {user2}")
```